# cron-apt informed me that there are pending security updates on my Debian system but I can't find the corresponding announcement. How shall I proceed?

Tags: debian, security, software-updates

Today, cron-apt informed me that there are pending security updates on my Debian stable system:

```
CRON-APT RUN [/etc/cron-apt/config]: Tue Jan 25 04:00:01 CET 2022
CRON-APT SLEEP: 3076, Tue Jan 25 04:51:17 CET 2022
CRON-APT ACTION: 3-download
CRON-APT LINE: /usr/bin/apt-get -o quiet=1 dist-upgrade -d -y -o APT::Get::Show-Upgraded=true
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-image-5.10.0-9-amd64
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bsdextrautils bsdutils eject libblkid1 libmount1 libsmartcols1 libuuid1
  mount util-linux util-linux-locales
10 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3561 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/main amd64 bsdutils amd64 1:2.36.1-8+deb11u1 [148 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/main amd64 util-linux amd64 2.36.1-8+deb11u1 [1141 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/main amd64 mount amd64 2.36.1-8+deb11u1 [186 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/main amd64 bsdextrautils amd64 2.36.1-8+deb11u1 [145 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/main amd64 libblkid1 amd64 2.36.1-8+deb11u1 [193 kB]
Get:6 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/main amd64 libmount1 amd64 2.36.1-8+deb11u1 [212 kB]
Get:7 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/main amd64 libsmartcols1 amd64 2.36.1-8+deb11u1 [158 kB]
Get:8 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/main amd64 libuuid1 amd64 2.36.1-8+deb11u1 [83.9 kB]
Get:9 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/main amd64 eject amd64 2.36.1-8+deb11u1 [102 kB]
Get:10 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/main amd64 util-linux-locales all 2.36.1-8+deb11u1 [1192 kB]
Fetched 3561 kB in 0s (47.6 MB/s)
Download complete and in download only mode
```

However, looking at https://www.debian.org/security/, I do not find a matching announcement:

> **Recent Advisories**
>
> These web pages include a condensed archive of security advisories posted to the debian-security-announce list.
>
> [21 Jan 2022] DSA-5052-1 usbview security update
> [20 Jan 2022] DSA-5051-1 aide security update
> [20 Jan 2022] DSA-5050-1 linux security update
> [15 Jan 2022] DSA-5048-1 libreswan security update
> ...

So, either (1) the announcement is delayed or (2) something fishy is going on. (I am aware that the probability for (1) is much higher than for (2), but still...)

**How shall I proceed to verify that this is indeed a genuine and benign security update?** I tried looking at the package information page of one of the updated packages (https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/bsdutils), but the "Debian Changelog" link on the right-hand side shows that the last modification was half a year ago.

---

Notes:

- While I am interested in an answer to this particular case, I am more interested in a *general* answer on how to proceed in such a case (see the bolded question above).
- If you think that this question is more suitable for security.se, feel free to migrate.

Comment: The `linux-util` update is announced on the list, and [looking at the specific CVEs](https://seclists.org/oss-sec/2022/q1/66), it involves `libmount`, which may explain the `libmount1` and `eject` updates etc. I'm assuming the others are also related.  If a library if updated, you may also want to update the software that uses that library.

Comment: @they: You're right. I must have overlooked it and didn't bother to check the mailing list archive after seeing the "recent advisories" list directly on debian.org/security. I'll self-answer my question.

Comment: @they all the packages come from the same source package, which is why they were all updated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you still trust the infrastructure, you can find out what changed by requesting the changelogs on your system; for example

```
$ apt changelog util-linux/bullseye-security
util-linux (2.36.1-8+deb11u1) bullseye-security; urgency=high

  * Non-maintainer upload by the Security Team.
  * include/strutils: Add ul_strtou64() function
  * libmount: fix UID check for FUSE umount [CVE-2021-3995]
  * libmount: fix (deleted) suffix issue [CVE-2021-3996]

 -- Salvatore Bonaccorso <carnil@debian.org>  Thu, 20 Jan 2022 21:10:35 +0100

...
```

(This queries the changelog from the repositories, it doesn’t require you to apply the upgrades.)

In your case, all the updated packages come from the `util-linux` source package, so they will all show the same changelog. While the fix only involves `libmount`, uploading a fixed source package means rebuilding all the binary packages it produces, and shipping them all as security updates.

This information is also available on [the package tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/util-linux), which offers links to [the changelog](https://tracker.debian.org/media/packages/u/util-linux/changelog-2.36.1-8deb11u1) and [the security tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/util-linux) (among many others). The security tracker was down when the question was written, which might explain why some of the other pages aren’t updated as you’d expect; [the DSA was sent out on January 24](https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/2022/msg00021.html).

If you want to check what changed, you can download the original and updated source code:

```
$ apt source util-linux/{stable,bullseye-security}
```

and compare the downloaded tarballs — in most cases, only the `.debian` tarball, `util-linux_2.36.1-8.debian.tar.xz` and `util-linux_2.36.1-8+deb11u1.debian.tar.xz` in this case:

```
$ mkdir ulo uls; tar xf util-linux_2.36.1-8.debian.tar.xz -C ulo; tar xf util-linux_2.36.1-8+deb11u1.debian.tar.xz -C uls
$ diff -urN ulo uls | less
```

Answer (score 6):

The "Recent Advisories" list on the Debian home page is outdated, check the mailing list archives (https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/) instead.

There, you'll find that [the advisory for util-linux](https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/2022/msg00021.html) has been sent yesterday. As mentioned in the comments, that bug involves `libmount`, which explains the other package updates.